# Multiple User Remote Desktop Azure

Tags: azure

How can i setup my Azure server to allow multiple users login to my server at the same time. For now, only one user can remote to my Azure server. I will be kicked out if another user in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change group policy settings in gpedit.msc as below

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections

Then you can change the following settings:

- Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session
- Limit number of connections

It is important to note that if multiple users are using this server and it is not purely for administration changes (Think remote desktop, Terminal Services), you will need to set up a remote desktop server with the appropriate licensing per user (RDS CALs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I have tried to config as your comment. But it still not work.

Comment: Need help on this